# Typescript ternary operator short form

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am inside a for loop trying to add up a number. The code is working fine, but I was asking myself if there might be shorter form for the following line:

```
price = ve.select ? price + ve.price : price;
```

if `ve.select` is true, the price is increased by `ve.price`, if its false, then price stays.
I am searching for something similar like this line (I know this code snippet does not work):

```
price = ve.select ? price + ve.price;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several options:

1. An `if` statement

   ```
   if (ve.select) {
       price += ve.price;
   }
   ```

   Or if you prefer it on one line:

   ```
   if (ve.select) price += ve.price;
   ```
2. The conditional operator version you've shown:

   ```
   price = ve.select ? price + ve.price : price;
   ```

   ...but note that it does an unnecessary assignment when `ve.select` is falsy (though as `price` is presumably a simple variable that's not an issue; with an object property that might be an accessor property it can matter).
3. Using the `&&` (logical AND) operator:

   ```
   ve.select && price += ve.price;
   ```

   But note that this is really just an `if` statement in disguise.
4. [Tamás Sallai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63884338/157247) providing an alternative use of the conditional operator (`price += ve.select ? ve.price : 0;`).

Answer (score 3):

I'd reverse the ternary and use `+=`:

```
price += ve.select ? ve.price : 0;
```