# Is there a short version of the ternary operator in typescript to use in the templates?

Tags: typescript, conditional-operator, undefined-reference

I have not been able to found a question that addresses this, other than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63883568/typescript-ternary-operator-short-form) which I think is not applied to templates.

I would like to know if there is something similar to this perl `defined-or` operator `//`.

Where I want to use a value if exists, otherwise nothing:

```perl
my $value = $variable_if_exists // $if_not_this_one;
```

Which is the short version for:

```perl
my $value = $variable_if_exists ? $variable_if_exists : $if_not_this_one;
```

Is there something similar in angular, I found my self in many scenarios writing this:

```js
{{ item.propery ? item.propery : ''}}
```

And I don't think it looks nice in code, and makes you change two variable in the same place if something is not as expected.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković - The Nullish coalescing operator will not meet the needs of the OP. The OP is specific about the first variable "not exist[ing]" - try `let a = b ?? 22` to see what I mean.

Comment: Don't leave the decision until the template. Create a property on your view model or that encapsulates the necessary choice, then use that new property. Ultimately, you don't want a lot of logic in your views anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In Typescript and Javascript you can use the `||` operator not just on boolean variables, but also for chaining other expressions. Like this:

`{{ $if_evaluates_to_some_truish_value || $value_else  }}`

"Truish" values, are all values except from `false`, `0`, `''`, `null`, or `undefined`.
If the first variable is "falsy", the expression after the `||` operator will be evaluated.

Comment: David - have you tried an assignment using your syntax? Something like `let a = b || 22;`? You might be surprised at the result that kind of undoes your answer. But that is precisely what the OP asks for "_if the first doesn't exist..._". I didn't down vote you but you should rethink your answer.

Comment: I used this several times before. I created a small [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-galois-ky6my?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) with several assignments using Typescript 4.1.5 (Angular 11). Take a look at the console to show the outputs. One thing I realized is, that an empty string `''` is also a "falsy" value (I added this to the original answer). I'm not sure how the result should undo my answer?

Comment: Because a nonexistent `b` !== an undefined `b` - you created `b` in every one of your cases. My point is directly related to a **non-existant** variable - the logical OR will throw and complain that `b` does not exist. Try it, you'll see.

Comment: I added two new cases to the codesandbox. Case 10 shows another (technically) working example, although the linter already shows an issue. Here we address a nonexistent property of a valid object. Case 11 shows your line, which results in the reference error. As far as my understanding goes, the problem with this line is not related to the `||` operator, but to the fact that there is no valid symbol `b` at all. The question we should ask here for better understanding is: What is the difference of a not defined `b` (linter message of case 11) and a not existent `b` (linter message of case 10)?

Comment: Yes, that is the question to ask - the OP. If the Op has no created variable on the left side of the `||`, then, as I've stated, your answer is not a fix. If, on the other hand the OP has a variable that is created but "falsy", then your answer is spot on.

Comment: honestly, though, shorting and shorthand because "it doesn't look nice" is an interesting approach to software development. Thanks for indulging my comments.

Comment: I agree with that :)

Comment: @RandyCasburn I mean that I have to write duplicated code and I ask the question because in perl where I'm more familiar with it there is such an operator, not such aesthetics. Use case is showing properties of an object if they exist, and I find redundand writing two times every time each property in an object with 30 keys.

Comment: @nck this:   "_Use case is showing properties of an object if they exist_" - the code in your question is confused on this note - namely the `$variable ? $variable : $other_variable` construct is _not_ object property access.